# How do I find the most dominant bit of a position in the given set of numbers?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Example:

```
11:  01011  
18:  10010  
 2:  00010    

Ans: 00010
```

At position zero (right most), I have more 0s than the number of 1s. Hence my answer should be 0. Similarly, at position one, I have 1 as the dominant bit, and so on.

Is there a way to find this using basic bitwise operators or should I use any other bitmasks that could achieve this result? I am looking for a O(1) solution for the same.

Comment: bitwise operations are all or nothing operations. There is no concept of 'dominant bit'. I think you will have to move beyond simple bit operations.

Comment: `I am looking for a O(1) solution for the same.` That's impossible. If you have a set of 100 numbers, how can you find the answer in the same time it takes for a set of 3 numbers? At a minimum you need to read each of the numbers in the set, which will be O(n). The best you can do for the entire algorithm is likely O(n log n)

Answer (score 2):

If you have exactly three inputs x, y, z, you can use

```
 (x & y) | (z & (x | y))
```

Similar formulas could probably be found for any other constant number of inputs.